Can the faith experience upheld by fideism be considered a case of phenomenologically experiencing or observing God?
I was intrigued by the question Is observation the only way to indicate that God is real? and this answer, which suggests fideism as an alternative to the observational epistemology proposed by the OP. This led me to ponder whether the faith central to fideism might be divinely inspired. It seems plausible that such faith could be understood as a gift from the divine, bestowed upon the individual. If so, the person receiving this gift would be, in essence, phenomenologically experiencing God's self-revelation—an awareness in their consciousness of His existence made profoundly obvious to them, which would not be possible otherwise.
After all, when someone transitions from a state of lacking genuine faith to possessing it (and assuming for the sake of argument that God does exist), something significant must shift within their consciousness during that conversion experience. This implies that the individual would phenomenologically observe or become aware of the divine gift of faith being granted to them at that moment.
Could fideism, then, be understood as a particular case of phenomenologically experiencing or becoming aware of God through this gift of faith?

Previous question I asked on fideism to keep in mind: How can fideism's pursuit of truth through faith be considered a sound epistemology when mutually exclusive religious beliefs are accepted on faith?

The only problem with this line of thought is that faith is not a reliable means of ascertaining truth.  In general, the most common answers to questions of the form, “How do you know your faith is reliable?” tend to boil down to, “I have faith in the reliability of my faith.”

It seems kind of like asking about qualia. Or maybe free will, or other insolubles.

Interesting question...for myself, I consider internal experience to be a type of evidence in its own right, and thus wouldn't consider a reliance on that as true fideism, but maybe I misunderstand the term.  I heard of one Christian philosopher, tongue-in-cheek, defining a "fideist" something like, "Anyone who emphasizes reason [i.e., external evidence and arguments] less than you do." Meaning that the term is sometimes used in a bit of a fuzzy and relative way.

Not necessarily. God may implant innate ideas and/or attitudes that lead to faith in him as a divine gift, but pondering those ideas is no more experiencing God than reading Plato is experiencing ancient Greece. The direct mystical/revelatory experiences that you seem to have in mind stand out from generic influences, with a roundabout link to God, upon which faith may be based. Not even faith inspired emotional exaltation is necessarily a direct experiencing of God, although it could, of course, indicate divine revelation.

If God gave you the faith, then it wouldn't be yours, would it? No better than if God revealed godself to everyone irrefutably.

@PeterRarnkin As a Christian, you should probably believe in the gift of faith, don't you? Would you set this apart from fideism?

@Conifold But when a person goes from being non-believer to believer under some definition of "faith" that God approves of (assuming for the sake of argument that God exists), wouldn't that transition/conversion in itself involve a phenomenological experience of this acquisition of genuine faith? How can you suddenly get an infusion of faith that completely changes your worldview and fail to notice it?

Acquisition of genuine faith may involve God revealing himself to the person, many denominations hold that this happens in certain rituals. But it not  does not have to. Life changing events that overturn person's thinking and attitudes do happen and are not always related to religion.

@user80226 So I see 1 Cor 12 as talking about a gift of peculiarly strong faith for certain Christians, like a specialty, while saving faith through the gospel is for all.  It is a gift in a sense, because Jesus had to die to make it happen, and the Holy Spirit must convict and convince.  But it requires us to make a decision to believe as well, so a gift we must sign for, if you will.  Not sure if that answers your question...I may need to read up on fideism, as I always thought it meant belief with zero reason or evidence at all, even internal, which I think would go against Heb 11:1.

@PeterRankin "But it requires us to make a decision to believe as well" - Are you talking about direct doxastic voluntarism?

@user80226 I think so, but maybe with the caveat that I also think there are often upstream goals and biases that can act as an epistemological "thumb on the scales" against an important claim, which must be acknowledged with a willingness to change them if necessary for the sake of truth, before such voluntarism is realistic?  E.g. I think Jesus was saying something similar in John 5:44.

@PeterRankin Direct doxastic voluntarism is an extremely controversial view. What are your thoughts on the arguments against direct doxastic voluntarism?

@user80226 To me, they seem to overgeneralize; i.e., certainly, many beliefs cannot be willed for reasons they cite. But for instance, in cases where the evidence is already weighty enough to have tipped the scales of normal, everyday, practical epistemology, yet it's counterweighted by goals and desires, I do think we have control to acknowledge and remove those counterweights from consideration, making direct voluntarism realistic.  I'd cite politics as a great counterexample: many times, people believe what they want to believe, both about their candidate, and about the opponent!  :)

@PeterRankin Is your position that the evidence in this debate is already weighty enough?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
